# Groovy script - add node as child at index 0

Tags: xml, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Im having issues being able to add a node to the 0 index of the node children.

I am able to append a node to the end but cant figure out how to get one at the front.

my code looks like this at the moment.

```
def setupProjectXML(workspace, environment, client) {
    def projectFile = new XmlParser().parse(new File("${workspace}/jenkinsProject.xml"))

    projectFile.appendNode("set", [name : "m4"])
    projectFile.appendNode("set", [name : "universalM4"])
    projectFile.appendNode("set", [name : "restoreState"])
    projectFile.appendNode("set", [name : "staging"])

    println(projectFile.toString())
}
```

I have tried a few different way using New Node() and add for a NodeList but this crashes the script anytime I use the Node constructor.

This error is

```
an exception which occurred:
in field collector
in field abnormal
in field outcome
in field body
in field step
in field thread
in field this$0
in field returnAddress
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field parent
in field parent
in field capture
in field def
in field closures
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2b1645bc
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this.

```
def setupProjectXML(workspace, environment, client) {
    def projectFile = new XmlParser(false,true).parse(new File("${workspace}/jenkinsProject.xml"))
    projectFile.appendNode("set", [name : "m4"])
    projectFile.appendNode("set", [name : "universalM4"])
    projectFile.appendNode("set", [name : "restoreState"])
    projectFile.appendNode("set", [name : "staging"]) projectFile.children().get(0).replaceNode(projectFile.children().get(projectFile.children().size()-1))
projectFile.children().get(1).replaceNode(projectFile.children().get(projectFile.children().size()-2))
projectFile.children().get(2).replaceNode(projectFile.children().get(projectFile.children().size()-3))
projectFile.children().get(3).replaceNode(projectFile.children().get(projectFile.children().size()-4))

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("${workspace}/jenkinsProject.xml")
XmlNodePrinter nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(fileWriter))
nodePrinter.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
nodePrinter.print(projectFile)
}
```

Its an ugly way of doing it and I had to add empty nodes inside of my xml class to use for replacing. Still not sure why I cant call new Node().

Answer (score 2):

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText('''<a><b c="d"/></a>''')
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)

xml.children().add(0, new Node(null, 'set', [x:'y'], 'text'))
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>
  <b c="d"/>
</a>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>
  <set x="y">text</set>
  <b c="d"/>
</a>
```

Comment: The only issue with this is anytime I try to use Node's constructor I get an error. Im calling this function through Jenkins which may be why it doesn't work.

an exception which occurred:
in field collector
in field abnormal....